# Is there a parrot grade stain?

Tags: staining

I have an African Grey Parrot and she goes through colored parrot blocks like crazy.

I would like to make my own parrot toys out of wood, but I have no idea what to color the wood with. It seems like the typical colors are; yellow, red, blue, green.

Does anyone have experience making colored wooden toys for parrots?

Comment: food dyes would probably work

Comment: Welcome to WSE. Try mixing the colors. Red + yellow + blue should give you grey. Also red + green = grey, (but with less control of the shade)

Comment: Does the parrot _really_ care what color the blocks are? Maybe just give her some wooden blocks to chew on and you can pretend they're lovely colors...

Comment: First thing I thought of is basically what @FreeMan said, is it important to *her* that the blocks are coloured? I realise parrots may have colour vision, but perhaps the most important thing is that they're sort of chew toys and not the colour. If the colour IS important however food dyes could be a good solution, but you could also try watercolour paints. Many of these are slightly sweet because they're made with dextrin or honey.

Comment: Experiment with paint made for children to use. "children's paint non-toxic" in search returns lots of choices.